# Summary of one variable for every other combination of variables in python / pandas / numpy (or Excel)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, csv

I am working on analysing the results of a model search. The results is saved in an excel file, but could easily be imported python (or another environment if necessary).
The data look something like this (this is a simplified version in terms of number of columns and rows):

[image: what i have]

I want to analyse how kappa varies with test data, so i want to know the min, max and average kappa with constant number of classes, dataset type, and subject number constant. this would look something like this:
[image: what i want]

I have fooled around with pandas.groupy(), but i cant seem to quite figure out how to do this. Any help would be much appriciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY:

Replace `c1,c2,c3,c4` with appropriate values:

```
df.groupby(['c1', ‘c2’, ‘c3]).agg({'c4': [min, max, np.mean]})
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but this was excactly what i was looking for, thank you very much!